# mensateaser [level 0] (part 1)

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

What should be the value of the bottom row in our

Euro 2012 Football themed grid?

[image]

Comment: Er, not that I'm not grateful, but Glorfindel had the correct answer first, and the reasoning was okay. I just pointed out how it's a mathematical problem. He should get the accepted answer bonus, not me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Glorfindel is correct, but there's an algebraic approach to it.

Let the shirt be *x*, the shorts be *y*, and the ball be *z*.

With that in mind, we now have:

> 2x + 2y = 100
>
> 3x + z = 145
>
> x + y + 2z = 100
>
> 2x + y + z = ??

Now, we can solve for two variables, then use the substitution method. Taking the easiest, we get:

> 2x + 2y = 100 -> 2y = -2x + 100 -> y = -x + 50
>
> 3x + z = 145 -> z = -3x + 145
>
> x + (-x + 50) + 2(-3x + 145) = 100

This equates out to:

> x - x + 50 - 6x + 290 = 100 -> 50 - 6x + 290 = 100 -> -6x + 340 = 100 -> -6x = -240 -> x = 40

Now that we know what *x* is, we can solve the rest.

> 2(40) + 2y = 100 -> 80 + 2y = 100 -> 2y = 20 -> y = 10
>
> 40 + 10 + 2z = 100 -> 50 + 2z = 100 -> 2z = 50 -> z = 25
>
> 2(40) + 10 + 25 = 115

This was more a mathematical problem than a puzzle, though.

Answer (score 10):

I think the answer is

> 115

My reasoning - I'm not sure what the blue & white figure is, but it looks like a shawl to me:

> In the leftmost column, we have two shawls and two shirts which add up to 100. That means one shawl and one shirt add up to 50. Subtract that from the second row, and we're left with two balls being equal to 50. Which means the **ball** has a value of **25**. Substitute that in the third column - we get that three shirts are equal to 120, so the **shirt** has a value of **40**. We already know one shawl plus one shirt equals 50, so the **shawl** has a value of 10. Therefore, the value of the bottom row is 40+25+40+10 = **115**.